# How can I configure `org-latex-preview` on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, emacs, org-mode

I am struggling to get my org-latex-preview works on my windows box. It worked perfectly on Linux, but no success yet on Windows. Here is my configuration:

```
  (org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvipng)

  (org-preview-latex-image-directory (concat temporary-file-directory "ltximg/"))
```

On Windows, I have MikTex installed and they are in the PATH, I got this error message when I tried to use org-latex-preview though

`c:/Users/my-user-name/AppData/Local/Temp/orgtexD2Xyuq.div` wasn't produced. Please adjust `dvipng` part of `org-preview-latex-process-alist`.  And I just check, `orgtexD2Xyuq.div`  indeed not produced, the `orgtexD2Xyuq.tex` was produced under the temp folder.

Comment: Please take the [tour].